# How to set specific rules to all data stored in real-time database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am doing an online library system storing the file name,download url of the book(from firebase storage) and the authd.uid of the user in real-time database what I want to do is to update the database rules and to allow only the user with the uid stored in data to access the data

that is my javascript code to put the values in database it works for me
but the problem is that user cannot read the data

```
const database = firebase.database();
const postKey=database.ref(postBook+'/').push().key;  

const postData={
    url:downloadURL,
    name:bookFile.name,
    uid:user.uid
};
updates[postBook+'/'+postKey]=postData;
firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

This is what my database looks like:

```
polsdatabase-f8594
    New Microsoft Excel Worksheet
        -LnrUtJIMHQHYfrfZQ7Z
            name: "New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx"
            uid: "Sju1GhAo24PEvZ1tjmVNKwvYnIy1"
            url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pol..."
    New Text Document
         -LnrWCA8dYwx6STtwjZT
             name: "New Text Document.txt"
             uid: "Sju1GhAo24PEvZ1tjmVNKwvYnIy1"
             url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pol..."
    personal online library
         -LnrW3gbE24_ifGE6JZL
             name: "personal online library.txt"
             uid: "Sju1GhAo24PEvZ1tjmVNKwvYnIy1"
             url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pol..."
```

that is what I tried to do with database rules but it is not working for me

```
{
    /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
    "rules": {
        ".read": "data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hafsa and welcome to Stack Overflow! Since the database rules are very dependent on the database structure, could you please include how your database is organized?

Comment: thanks Jeremy but i did not understand what do you mean by how database is organized

Comment: You can take a screenshot of the database, or type it out manually. Without seeing the database structure (what database nodes are under what parent node) it will be more difficult to help.